# BASH - Write output of a function to a file

Tags: bash, writetofile

I have a situation where I have a .sh file full of functions. Each of the functions has an echo in them echoing them to the console.

```
#!/bin/bash

getLogTimestamp() {
    echo TimeStamp:  $(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.130Z)
}

getDisplayName(){
echo Device  Name: $(awk -F'=' '/^CARBON_LITE_PLAYER_ID=.*/ { print $2;}' /home/benja/app/.env)
}

getDeviceIPAddress(){
echo Device IP Address: $(hostname -i)
}

getSystemUptime(){
echo System UpTime: $(uptime)
}

getDateTimeInfo(){
echo Time Sync Status: "$(timedatectl status | awk '/Warning/{exit} 1')"
}

getMemoryInfo() {
    arr=( $(free -h) )
    keys=("${arr[@]::8}")
    vals=("${arr[@]:8:12}")
    for i in ${!keys[@]}; { printf -v data[i] "%s: %s, " "${keys[i]}" "${vals[i]}"; }
    data="${data[@]}"
    echo Memory:  ${data%,*}
}

getDiskInfo()
{
  arr=($(df -h))
    keys=("${arr[@]::6}")
    vals=("${arr[@]:7:100}")
    for i in ${!keys[@]}; { printf -v data[i] "%s: %s, " "${keys[i]}" "${vals[i]}"; }
    data="${data[@]}"
    echo Disk:  ${data%,*}

}

getDisplayState(){
    STATE=$(/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -s | awk '/state/  {print $2}')
    if STATE=0x40001
        then
            echo Display State: VC_SDTV_NTSC, VC_HDMI_UNPLUGGED
            exit

    elif STATE=0x40002
        then
            echo Display State: VC_SDTV_NTSC, VC_HDMI_ATTACHED
            exit
    elif STATE=0x120002
        then
            echo Display State: VC_SDTV_ATTACHED, VC_SDTV_CP_INACTIVE, VC_HDMI_ATTACHED
            exit
    elif STATE=0x120005
        then
            echo Display State: VC_SDTV_ATTACHED, VC_SDTV_CP_INACTIVE, VC_HDMI_UNPLUGGED, VC_HDMI_DVI
    elif STATE=0x120016
        then
            echo Display State: VC_SDTV_ATTACHED, VC_SDTV_CP_INACTIVE, VC_HDMI_ATTACHED, VC_HDMI_DVI, VC_HDMI_HDCP_UNAUTH
            exit
    elif STATE=0x12001a
        then
            echo Display State: VC_SDTV_ATTACHED, VC_SDTV_CP_INACTIVE, VC_HDMI_ATTACHED, VC_HDMI_HDMI, VC_HDMI_HDCP_UNAUTH
            exit
    elif STATE=0x12001a
        then
            echo Display State: VC_SDTV_ATTACHED, VC_SDTV_CP_INACTIVE, VC_HDMI_ATTACHED, VC_HDMI_HDMI
            exit
    elif STATE=0x120009
        then
            echo  Display State: VC_SDTV_ATTACHED, VC_SDTV_CP_INACTIVE, VC_HDMI_UNPLUGGED, VC_HDMI_HDMI
            exit
    fi
}
```

I have a second .sh file (which I have imported the function file into and I can call the functions and they echo to the screen just fine.

My problem is that I can not seem to write the function output to file:

```
. /home/benja/app/scripts/log-helper-functions.sh

# RSH -We are logging this data every time this script runs
echo ---------------------------------- >>/home/benja/app/logs/carbonlite-guardian.log

getDisplayName >>/home/benja/app/logs/carbonlite-guardian.log

getDeviceIPAddress >>/home/benja/app/logs/carbonlite-guardian.log

getLogTimestamp >>/home/benja/app/logs/carbonlite-guardian.log

getSystemUptime >>/home/benja/app/logs/carbonlite-guardian.log

getDateTimeInfo >>/home/benja/app/logs/carbonlite-guardian.log

getMemoryInfo >>/home/benja/app/logs/carbonlite-guardian.log

getDiskInfo >>/home/benja/app/logs/carbonlite-guardian.log

getDisplayStaten >>/home/benja/app/logs/carbonlite-guardian.log
echo ---------------------------------- >>/home/benja/app/logs/carbonlite-guardian.log
# RSH end
```

I don't want to hardcode the functions to write to the file as they are meant to be reusable, so how do I go about writing to a file in this instance?

TIA,
Ron

Comment: Show how you import your first file in the second.

Comment: . /home/benja/app/scripts/log-helper-functions.sh

Comment: I tried your code, besides a couple typos (getDisplayStaten) and after replacing paths for my system, it all works ok.  I run it in a bash, Linux,.

Comment: I am using Arch-Linux on a Raspberry Pi, and Im getting these errors:

[benja@hostname ~]$ sudo /home/benja/app/scripts/carbonlite-guardian.sh
[E] No device present
/home/benja/app/scripts/carbonlite-guardian.sh: line 32: DISPLAYINFO: command not found

That is the exact output when running the script

Comment: It is working! for some reason it is not writing the last line:

echo -------------------------------------

Comment: After `cglog="/home/benja/app/logs/carbonlite-guardian.log"` you can use `>> "${cglog}"`